# Django and HTML - placing a div inside a <td> element renders it in the wrong place

Tags: html, css, django, html-table

I am trying to render a table `<td>` element with a `<div>` inside in order to do a AJAX call to replace what is contained within the `<div>`. However when I look into my html page the `<div>` is in the complete wrong place. I am using the `{% include %}` functionality of django, is this the reason?

**main.html**

```
 <table class='table'>
      <thead>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
           <td> data </td>
           <td> data </td>
            {% include 'results/other_templates/data_details.html' %}
      </tr>
 </table>
```

**data_details.html**

```
<div id="{{obj.id}}-detail">
    <td>blah blah blah</td>
    <td>blah blah blah</td>
</div>
```

Looking at my html page source when the page is rendered, it renders like this:

```
 <div id="263-detail">
 </div>

 <table class='table'>
      <thead>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
           <td> data </td>
           <td> data </td>
           <td> blah blah blah </td>
           <td> blah blah blah </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

The div element is now outside of the table. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is not a valid html element inside table according to w3c.

Then, browsers try to fix your table layout by removing not allowed elements.

Additionaly your `thead` layout is invalid too. It should look like that:

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>headers</th>
        <th>headers</th>
        <th>headers</th>
        <th>headers</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Use the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) if you're not sure if your HTML syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

`div` should be inside `td` as **tr** could not take `div` directly.

So:

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
           <th>headers</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
           <td> data </td>
           <td> data </td>
           <!-- This line -->
           <td>
               {% include 'results/other_templates/data_details.html' %}
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

#### EDIT

As suggested by @Magiczne, `th` should also be inside `tr`:

```
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>headers</th>
         <th>headers</th>
         <th>headers</th>
         <th>headers</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
```

Also, your `data_details.html` should also be fixed to sthg like:

```
<div id="{{obj.id}}-detail">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>blah blah blah</td>
            <td>blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i realise what I was doing now, I think having it split up made me think it would look like something else!!

Comment: Thas is not the good answer, because of contents of `data_details.html` it will still be a invalid html syntax.

Comment: @trouselife please check my answer below.